# Is it safe for two threads to read different regions of the same block of memory?

Tags: multithreading, delphi

Is it safe to use the same memory chunk in more than one thread partially like below:

```
const
  BIFFER_SIZE = 1024;
var
  ABuffer :PChar;
  ABufferWrite :PChar;
  ABufferEnd :PChar;
begin
  GetMem(ABuffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
  ABufferEnd := ABuffer + BUFFER_SIZE;
  ABufferWrite := ABuffer + BUFFER_SIZE div 2;
end;
```

Assume thread 0 is writing between [ABufferWrite..ABufferEnd] while thread 1 is reading between [ABuffer..ABufferWrite-1].

I think it is okay. Am I right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no problem with two threads accessing distinct regions of memory in terms of correctness.

The issue that may affect you are the performance problems due to [false sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing). You can avoid those by making sure that there is at least a whole cache line of unused space between the two regions of memory.

If you want to learn more about false sharing I refer you to one of Herb Sutter's articles on the subject: [Eliminate False Sharing](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/eliminate-false-sharing/217500206).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've arranged that each thread is using its own portion of the memory block without touching the portion that belongs to another thread. Sure, that's fine. And because the threads are not sharing any part of the memory, you don't need any synchronization either.